# WebView Navigation Not Working

Tags: javascript, android, webview, navigation

I’m trying to add navigation links to a WebView in my Android app but WebView.canGoBack() always returns false.  I’ve read a few posts on SO that said it’s a bug and have tried different suggestions including shouldOverrideUrlLoading() to no avail.   So I decided that it just doesn’t work and added navigation links to my web page instead:

```
<a href="javascript:window.history.back()" title="Back"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
<a href="javascript:window.history.forward()" title="Forward"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>
```

I also have JavaScript enabled:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

The links work fine when the pages are opened in a browser such as Firefox on the device however, they fail to work when the page is viewed in the WebVeiw.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update - I tried targeting and compiling with API 28.  Same results.

Comment: BTW I am using a WebViewClient not WebChromeClient

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a bug in WebView.  I'm running Chrome v67.

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/android-webview-dev/YYxyjl2WZTA

WebView's history and associated canGoBack() and goBack() methods do not work properly when Google Chrome version 63.0.3239.111 is installed on the device. Uninstalling or disabling Google Chrome and its webview implementation solves the issue.

This issue ist tested and confirmed on Android versions 6.0.1, 7.1.2 and 8.1.0.

Issue description:
Saving the webview history does not work properly, when Chrome is installed. When you use webView.goBack() to navigate back to the page visited before, sometimes this page is skipped and the webView goes back to the first visited webpage. Other times the history is simply empty resulting in webView.canGoBack() returning false, although you had visited a page just before.

Workaround solution:
Uninstall chrome from device or disable it by using the System Developer Option 'WebView implementation'.

Google, please provide a Chrome update which solves this issue permanently. Our users are very confused by this inconsistent behavior. If this is not the right forum for developer topics, please advise in which forum or Google Group this issue should be posted and tracked.

Thank you very much in advance.